# Reading unlimited length input line without using string

Tags: c++, char

I would like to read unlimited length line of text from the input. I wish not to use string or any of it.

I tried that but it seems does not work. I always get the same output.

**I do not want to use: `string`, the input has to be of any length.**

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

char * getline(){
    char * buf = new char[10];
    int result = scanf("%as\n", &buf);
    if (result < 0) {
        if (NULL != buf)
            delete []buf;
        return NULL;
    }
    return buf;
}

int main(){
    char* haha =  getline();
    cout <<haha << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `std::string`?

Comment: And which part of your code allocating a 10-character buffer is intended to handle an "unlimited length line of text?"

Comment: "%as" in scanf is not in Standard C++. There is no way to fulfil your request in Standard C++ without using `string` or another container, or rolling your own loop. Also, `%s` only reads up to first whitespace, not the end of the line.

Comment: What compiler are you using? `%as` specifier is a nonportable GCC extension. And you aren't freeing it correctly anyway.

Comment: If you're happy with GCC exptensions you could use the GCC function `ssize_t getline(char **BUFPTR, size_t *N, FILE *FP);`

Comment: The fun part with std::string is that you can read in ANY length. Without worrying about the size.

Comment: Combine fgets() and realloc()

Comment: @Yoda Why do you want to avoid `std::string`? (people are asking you this because this determines the best answer to your question)

Comment: Hint 1: What is the type of `&buf`? Hint 2: Enable, and heed, all your compiler's warnings.

Answer (score 1):

`char * buf;` just creates the pointer variable, but does not allocate memory.

use: `buf = new char[...]`.

Obviously, since your computer has not got unlimited memory, you will need to specify a size instead of `...`

And delete it as: `delete [] buf`

But, I think the best solution is:

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read into a buffer that doesn't exist! Here `buf` points to an undefined location in memory, and the most likely outcome of this code is a crash. You must allocate some space (using `new[]`) before you can read data into it; and of course, that space must be of some well-defined size. You can always allocate a new, large buffer at any time, and copy the contents of the smaller one into it; this is how you "grow" memory blocks in C++, and it's how  `string` works internally.

Comment: but I would like to do not specifiy length of input, I thought that canf will allocate the `buf` for me.

Comment: @Yoda No, it will not. If you want to avoid using `std::string`, you have to reimplement that part of it yourself - read into a fixed-size buffer, check whether you've read it all, if not, allocate a larger buffer, copy, read another chunk, rinse, repeat.